# How to change my navigation title font and color both together?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change my custom navigation bar's background color and also its title font color , font style and font size. so i tried this code into the AppDelegate.swift file

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 162/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
 UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
 let navigationTitleFont = UIFont(name: "Poppins", size: 20)!
 let navigaiontitlecolor = UIColor.white

 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : navigaiontitlecolor]
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : navigationTitleFont]
```

i got the background color. my title font style and size both are ok. but my title font color is not ok. so i go for searching and i applied this link code
    [Change Both Title Text Color and Font in all Navigation Bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495713/change-both-title-text-color-and-font-in-all-navigation-bars) 
 but did not work in my case. what to do?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Check if it changed it elsewhere.

Comment: You didn't read the @matt's answer to the _exact_ same question.

Comment: @matt's answer didn't work .

Comment: are you sure @matt's answer is working or not? sir.

Comment: because it shows error to me like this: Use of unresolved identifier 'NSfontAttributedName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to change navigation title font and color both together:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: **YourFont**, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:**Your Color**]
```

Comment: thanks it's working .

Answer (score 1):

Below code will globally change the UINavigationBar style and also remove its bottom line. Just paste them to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` inside **AppDelegate**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 162/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Poppins", size: 20)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
    ]
```

Comment: This is the perfect way to set the "style" for the nav bar, but you should mention that this won't work if the nav bar is already displayed. It will change the appearance for the next nav bars that will be displayed. So this code has to be put in a perfect place to work ;).

Comment: Thanks @danypata, I editted my answer.